# Meaning of phrase “to stay alive”?

Tags: set-phrases

気をつけてな！

Is the meaning of this phrase “try to stay alive” or something like that? It’s like literally “keep your air attached to you”, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34556/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means be careful.  For example if you were about to step in a puddle your walking buddy might say "watch out" or something similar.